# Внутри класса не удаляет дубляжи из вектора целых чисел

Tags: алгоритм, vector, классы, c++

В комментарии кода пометил ошибку:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;

......................здесь есть функции..............

void UniqueIntVector(IntVector & iv){
std::sort(iv.begin(), iv.end());
iv.erase(unique(iv.begin(), iv.end()), iv.end());
}

class ComparingArray{
std::vector<IntVector> theGeneralVector;
private:
public:
ComparingArray(){};
~ComparingArray(){};

void PushDividers(const std::string str, const char div);
void PopDividers();

int GetMaxGeneralDivider();

bool IsNull() const;
 };

 void ComparingArray::PushDividers(const std::string str, const char div){
StringVector sv;
IntVector iv;

StringToVector(sv, str, div);
StringVectorToIntVector(iv, sv);

theGeneralVector.push_back(iv);
 }

 void ComparingArray::PopDividers(){
theGeneralVector.pop_back();
 }

 int ComparingArray::GetMaxGeneralDivider(){
if (!theGeneralVector.size())
    return 0;

for (int i = 0; i < (int)theGeneralVector.size(); i++)
    UniqueIntVector(theGeneralVector[i]); // не удаляет дубликаты!!!!!!!

return 0;
}

bool ComparingArray::IsNull() const{
     if ((theGeneralVector.size() == 0) || (theGeneralVector.size() == 1))
         return true;
 else
     return false;
}
```

Извиняюсь, если кому надоел.

Comment: @perfect: А в отладчике проходить пробовали?

Comment: Да как раз через отладчик и смотрю. Сортирует, но не удаляет. Хотя если вынести все это в main(), работает безукоризненно.

Comment: Сходу ничего такого не видно. Выложите весь код и тестовые данные на какой-нибудь "pastebin".

Comment: @perfect: А **внутри** функции `UniqueIntVector`?

Попробуйте переписать код вот так:

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)theGeneralVector.size(); i++)
    {
        IntVector& vec = theGeneralVector[i];
        UniqueIntVector(vec);
    }

И посмотрите содержимое `iv` внутри `UniqueIntVector` в начале и в конце выполнения функции, посмотрите содержимое `vec` до и после вызова `UniqueIntVector`, и наконец содержимое `theGeneralVector[i]` до и после итерации цикла.

Comment: Ошибка была чисто грамматическая, я не вызвал этот метод в классе. Всем спасибо, извиняюсь, что потревожил бестолку, спасибо @VladD'у. Все прекрасно работает.